# php download button without submiting back to page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, download

i have problem,my code is given below.

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['download_button']) === false && isset($_POST['download_button'])){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_real_name.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . (int)(filesize($file_path)));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_path);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="download_button" value="Download"" />
</form>
```

This is my current code but i dont want submit button. i want a normal button or a blank link that will start download.i have seen many website do this. i think with the help of javascript. anyone can help here?
i dont want user to know random name on the server of file or the location.

i mean to say there is other way to get download start with javascript or jquery sending request to php and the download start without submiting the form.?

Comment: which do you want - a link or "normal" button. And what's a "normal" button? And what relevance is "without submitting back to page"? You mean post to another page? The question is not clear, sorry.

Comment: i mean to say there is other way to get download start with javascript or jquery sending request to php and the download start.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $_GET use a hyperlink instead of a submit button.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['download']) && $_GET['download']){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: application/octetstream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_real_name.'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . (int)(filesize($file_path)));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file_path);
}
?>
<a href="?download=true">Download</a>
```

Comment: actually i dont want anyone to type ?download=true in url because
1. My download page pick up file from database with get, like download.php?id=123
2. anyone can type in url ?download=true i only want download start when they click the button

Answer (score 1):

An alternative route than $_GET:
Using jquery you can have a link that calls a javascript function,
and then you can access a php file on the fly. This will also require no refreshing of the page

```
function buttonClicked()
{
    $.ajax({
       url:'downloadpage.php',
       data:{'filename':'name of file'},
       type:'post')};
}


<a onclick="buttonClicked()">Download now</a>
```